# How to send proxy username and password with RestClient Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I'm using RestClient gem for a post request according to the documentation we can add proxy , but in my case proxy URL itself has authentication, how to achieve it with Restclient Gem

```
RestClient.proxy = "someurl"
RestClient.proxy_user_name = ??
RestClient.proxy_password = ??

request = RestClient::Request.new(
    :method => :post,
    :url => 'some_url',
    :user => '123',
    :password => '123',
    :payload => {
        :multipart => true,
        :file => File.new("somepath", 'rb')
   }
)
response = request.execute
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use the `RestClient::Request.execute` like this:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(
  method: :post,
  url: 'some_url',
  proxy: 'https://username:password@proxy_url:proxy_port' # will be parsed with URI.parse
)
```

Check the docs here: [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#proxy)

Comment: what's the url that you are using? they are using URi.parse on that proxy config